# How to return 3 fields in Json and popular chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a service in PHP returning the following:

```
[[1,"16846"],[2,"16858"],[3,"16923"],[4,"16891"]]
```

In my HTML I have ajax searching for this information;

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getDadosGrafico.php',
        dataType: 'json', // use this
        success: function(data) {
            var dados = data;
```

I need my chart to have 3 records, I already have all 3 columns in the database.
How can I make ajax identify the 3 columns

[image]

My code PHP

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $users = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $cont=1;
  $dataset1 = array();
  foreach ($users as $row) {
      $data = $row['data_reenvio'];
      $data_formatada=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data));

    $dataset1[] = array($cont , $row['total_sucesso'], $row['total_falha'], $row['total'] );
    $cont++;

  }
  print (json_encode($dataset1));
```

My Code HTML

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getDadosGrafico.php',
    dataType: 'json', // use this
    success: function(data) {
        var dados = data;

        // Graph Data ##############################################
        var graphData = [{
            // Visits
            data: dados, //[ [6, 1300], [7, 1600], [8, 1900], [9, 2100], [10, 2500], [11, 2200], [12, 2000], [13, 1950], [14, 1900], [15, 2000] ],
            color: '#71c73e'
        }, {
            // Returning Visits
            data: [ [1, 15500], [2, 16000], [3, 16550], [4, 16000], [5, 16800], [6, 16900], [7, 16800], [8, 16850], [9, 16830], [10, 17000] ],
            color: '#77b7c5',
            points: {
                radius: 4,
                fillColor: '#77b7c5'
            }
        }, {
            // Returning Visits
            data: [ [1, 17500], [2, 17000], [3, 17550], [4, 18000], [5, 18800], [6, 18900], [7, 18800], [8, 18850], [9, 18830], [10, 17000] ],
            color: '#77b7c5',
            points: {
                radius: 4,
                fillColor: '#0007c5'
            }
        }
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an object with 3 properties, each one with an array of arrays, like this:

```
{
  visits: [ [6, 1300], [7, 1600], [8, 1900], [9, 2100], [10, 2500], [11, 2200], [12, 2000], [13, 1950], [14, 1900], [15, 2000] ],
  returning_visitors: [ [1, 15500], [2, 16000], [3, 16550], [4, 16000], [5, 16800], [6, 16900], [7, 16800], [8, 16850], [9, 16830], [10, 17000] ],
  extra: [ [1, 17500], [2, 17000], [3, 17550], [4, 18000], [5, 18800], [6, 18900], [7, 18800], [8, 18850], [9, 18830], [10, 17000] ]
}
```

And then, you will use these object values on your code, like this:

```
      var graphData = [{
            // Visits
            data: dados.visits
            color: '#71c73e'
        }, {
            // Returning Visits
            data: dados.returning_visitors,
            color: '#77b7c5',
            points: {
                radius: 4,
                fillColor: '#77b7c5'
            }
        }, {
            // Returning Visits
            data: dados.extra,
            color: '#77b7c5',
            points: {
                radius: 4,
                fillColor: '#0007c5'
            }
        }
      ];
```

On your PHP code, I'm not sure, but I think that it would be something like this:

```
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $users = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $cont=1;

  $datasetTotalSucesso = array();
  $datasetTotalFalha = array();
  $datasetTotal = array();

  foreach ($users as $row) {
    $data = $row['data_reenvio'];
    $data_formatada=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data));

    $datasetdatasetTotalSucesso[] = array($cont , $row['total_sucesso']);
    $datasetTotalFalha[] = array($cont , $row['total_falha']);
    $datasetTotal[] = array($cont , $row['total'] );

    $cont++;

  }
  $obj = array('visits' => $datasetdatasetTotalSucesso, 'returning_visitors' => $datasetTotalFalha, 'extra' => $datasetTotal);
  print (json_encode($obj));
```

Comment: How do I do this in PHP

Comment: I edited my answer with what I think it's the answer for PHP.